# Xcode saving : home vs stop simulator

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, sqlite, ios-simulator

When I press play and then stop in Xcode, my code saves to my sqlite3 database. However, when I press play and then home instead of pressing stop, it doesn't save. I had the terminal open and checked the database in deriveddata each time I tested the saving function. I don't have any code in:

`(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`

nor do I have any code in:

`(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application`.

I save to the database directly when the user presses a button. What's the difference between the home button in the simulator and the stop button in Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

Home Button will **minimize your application** (applicationDidEnterBackground will be called) And pressing stop button **terminate your application**. By quick double pressing home button you can see minimized applications by tapping one of the application icon will make your app active again from backgound state.

Comment: Ok. What's the difference between double clicking the home button and exiting out of an app with the red circle versus pressing stop?